# Passing Values from view to Controller in ASP.Net MVC3 Razor using EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my ASP.Net MVC3 Razor project i have to implement `Search Customer` Profile. When I enter a name of the customer and click the button `Search` , the corresponding Customer data to be listed in a normal table .This is what i expecting to do.

**Currently this is what I have**

I have a textbox with a button is placed in a view named `SearchCustomer.cshtml` and it is associated with a controller named "SearchCustomer" and the resulting data is displayed in another view named `ViewCutomerData` and the controller associated with this is `ViewCutomerData`.

**My Problem**

When I click the search button with a name it is not passing to the controller so the second controller is displaying only the blank table .

**Questions**

- How to pass values from a view page like this to the controller ?
- Can we use a single Action to search data and to display the result in a table ?

Controller Code

```
        public ActionResult SearchCustomer()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult ViewCutomerData(string  cusmodel)
        {
            var data = from c in cus.CusModelData
                       where c.Name.Contains(cusmodel)
                       select c;

            return View(data.ToList());
        }
```

Search Customer

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewCutomerData", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
 {
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Enter Customer Name</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "ErrorMessagetext" })</div>
     </div>

     <table>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Search" /></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
```

Comment: The reason it doesn't pass is because your field is called Name, and your parameter is called cusmodel.  Make them the same and it will work.

Comment: @MystereMan  Wow Man now its working...Can u post the same as answer.And one more thing in my question is that can we use the same controller to hold both search and its result.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing single `string` . You can pass whole `model` to `controller action` like this and then use `property name` in the `model`

```
public ActionResult ViewCutomerData(CusModel cusmodel)
        {

            var data = from c in cus.CusModelData
                       where c.Name.Contains(cusmodel.Name)
                       select c;

            return View(data.ToList());


        }
```

Comment: Thats okay.Now i have tried this code.But i mean ,my question is how to pass that string value from searchCustomer to this viewCustomer.

Comment: still not able u get ur requirement :(

Comment: Hello ,Nitin did you understand my question?

Comment: No i got it ...Now its working .. @Mystere Man solved my first problem.can u able to solve the second question.